# IF statement : how to print names of columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

Here is my issue

I have this DataFrame :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':[1,2,3],
                   'Paul':[8,10,13],
                   'Mathieu':[18,20,2],
                   'Jacques':[2,1,70]})

df = df.set_index('Date')
```

My goal is to create an IF statement with those conditions : 
IF the last value of the rolling mean 2 days is < the rolling mean 3 days and the fist value (Day 1) is > the last value (Day 3) then print the name of the column.

This is what I started :

```
def test(data):
    end = data.iloc[-1]
    start = data.iloc[0]
    end_rolling_2D = data.rolling(2).mean().iloc[-1]
    end_rolling_3D = data.rolling(3).mean().iloc[-1]

    if end_rolling_2D < end_rolling_3D and start > end :
        print(data.columns)
```

But I have this Error :

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

And I don't really know how to solve that.I know that the aswer should be 'Mathieu' only because he's the only one that met the conditions.

I am very new to Python, so if anyone has an idea to solve that, you are welcome!

Thank you.

Comment: Remove `time-series` tag as this has nothing to with the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`start`, `end`, `end_rolling_2D` and `end_rolling_3D` are `Series` object, use [**`pd.Series.all()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.all.html)

Replace

```
if end_rolling_2D > end_rolling_3D and start > end
```

with

```
if ((end_rolling_2D>end_rolling_3D) & (start>end)).all()
```

To get the location where the condition is satisfied use [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

```
mask = (end_rolling_2D<end_rolling_3D) & (start>end)
print(df.columns[mask])
# Index(['Mathieu'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I made a mistake, it's end_rolling_2D<end_rolling_3D and I fixed it on the post. However I used your technique but I may have missed something, because when I use the function on my DataFrame, it doesn't give me any result

Comment: Because `((end_rolling_2D<end_rolling_3D) & (start>end)).all()` is `False`

Comment: Ok let’s forget about `(end_rolling_2D<end_rolling_3D)` and let’s just keep `(start>end).all()` for simplicity so that I can easily understand. 
We clearly see that start of ‘Mathieu’ is 18 and it is >  end of ‘Mathieu’ which is 2.
But if I run the fonction it still doesn’t give me anything, however it is `True`. 
I don’t really understand why

Comment: @Kben59  `.all` return `True` if all the values are Truthy else `False`. I suggest you go through the basics of pandas and NumPy. In this case `.all` using `.all` is irrelevant, you should use `boolean indexing` here.

Comment: @Kben59 Attached all the relevant links for understanding more about `boolean indexing` ;)

Comment: Thank you so much for you help, I'll check that immediatly!

Answer (score 0):

Change your function to:

```
def test(data):
    end = data.iloc[-1]
    start = data.iloc[0]
    end_rolling_2D = data.rolling(2).mean().iloc[-1]
    end_rolling_3D = data.rolling(3).mean().iloc[-1]

    if ((end_rolling_2D > end_rolling_3D) & (start > end)).all() :
        print(data.columns)
```

Please note that I have added brackets. And replaced `and` by `&`
However, I do not expect any data which satisfies your criteria.